# Libgdx Box2D controll collision response for a few specific objects only

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

In `Box2d`, as much as i understood, objects have a default collision response, which lets them stop movement or bounce back (if you set a restitution).
Also you can say, that the object is a sensor and so you can implement your own collision response.
Now i would like to use the default collision response for some kinds of collisions, while i want to have full controll of collisions with specific objects.
For example: A player should stop movement or bounce back, if he collides with a wall, but it should loose Hp, when he collides with a bullet and the bullet should be removed.
So i would like to have something like the contact filters, but the objects, which do not match the filter should react with the default behaivor.

Is something like this possible?
How can i do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `CollisionListener` and check the user data of your fixtures/bodies for the type. Then you can handle it however you want. If you don't want the player/bullet collision to have a response, you should disable the `Contact` in `preSolve` (via [`Contact.setEnabled(false)`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/Contact.html#setEnabled%28boolean%29)) and mark the bullet to be destroyed.

Having a powerful collision handling system is necessary in this case. I've created a gist which shows how I do it via socalled `CollisionHandler`s. which are responsible for each type of EntityA vs EntityB collisions. The `CollisionFilter` can already pre-filter the collisions in total and the `CollisionListener` will then determine the correct `CollisionHandler` and forward the callbacks to those. It uses reflection and might not be the fastest approach with a lot of bodies and collisions, but so far I didn't ran into any problems here.

[You can find the gist here.](https://gist.github.com/nooone/10593791)

Comment: If i disable a collision (like bullet vs. player) in presolve, would player vs wall (for example) be handled with the default behaivor?

Comment: Please carefully read the code in the gist. Each collision (for example bullet/player or player/wall) will have their own "contact lifecycle". That means in case two of those collisions happen, there will be twice a `beginContact`/`preSolve`/`postSolve`/`endContact`. Disabling one of them does not affect the other contact/collision at all. Thus they can also be handled by completely different handlers. One would disable the contact, the other would not.

Comment: I was reading this (https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Box2d) tutorial. If you read the last 2 sentences before the `kinematic bodies` chapter you see, that the ball of the example bounces on collision, even if you do not implement a contact listener. So there is a default behaivor. And i was wondering, how i can call this "handler" or whatever it is. I understood the rest but i am not sure how i can let Box2D handle the contacts i don't want to handle myself...

Comment: You don't call it, it is the default behaviour (having a collision-response). If you do NOT want it, then you have to disable the contact as described.

Comment: Ah okay so basicly i can handle the collisions i want in presolve, then disable it, while i ignore the others?

Comment: Exactly. If you use the code in my gist, you'd register only handlers for those collisions you want to handle differently, all others will just use the standard behaviour.

Comment: Thats exactly what i was looking for. English is not my native language so somtimes it is hard to explain what i mean^^
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

This basics is this :

http://pastebin.com/9vzZUbTT

All your fixture's user data should have a own specific name.

This works for me!

The entity class contains the body and fixture.

Edit: Might not what you want to have, but it's something

Edit2 : http://pastebin.com/Cw0R7hmq Something like this, there's probably alot of compile error, but I hope you get what I'm trying to say.

Comment: I see, that in the contact listener is an if, which controlls, if the collision is between the flower and the player, but does it use the deafult collision response, if it is not a collision between the flower and the player?

Comment: if it's not a collision between the flower and the player, then either check(player, contact) will return false, or check(flower, contact) will return false. Thus, the if statement in beginContact is false.

Comment: Yea i know, but how does it then react to collisions?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. But is it really neccesary to have runnables for this? Doesn't you have the possibility to just override the default response for some special collisions and use it for all others?

Comment: Maybe world.getContactList() will do the job?

Comment: @noone showed me the right way to do that. Anyways thanks for your help!